# Need to create a form which will search for posts that use Advanced Custom Fields map/location data and display the nearest post to the user

Tags: php, html, wordpress, geolocation, advanced-custom-fields

Need to create a form which will search for posts that use Advanced Custom Fields map/location data and display the nearest post to the user.

Any help or starting code will be helpful.

Thanks

I have tried a few plugins like Geo my WP and it doesnt do as I need. Wp geodirectory is a no go too.

I want the user to have three form fields. One for location (google pre filled) then to choose a category, then taxonomy. The results will find all posts linked and show the closest one to the user (with a  distance showed)

Answer (score 0):

Well this needs a custom plugin development, the requirements are very specific for a regular plugin.

I would do the following.

If you already are using ACF I imagine that your already have a custom post with a custom taxonomy right, so, in this custom plugin

1) Create a new WP REST endpoint  that accepts the user inputs

2) The endpoint callback should be  query the custom posts based on the meta fields using an WP_QUERY instance, retrieve the matched posts and send it back to the client to draw your map.

3) Create and endpoint to retrieve the categories and the taxonomy terms.

4) In the front-end side you will need to create a form with the data retrieved from the endpoints (step 3)

5) Submit the data to the endpoint (step 2) and retrieve the posts

6) Draw  your map.

This are a very generic steps and unfortunately I can't give you any code based on a wide question.

Answer (score 0):

It depend, you could use postal code, but the best is to use latitude and longitude with Google Maps API. There somes functions with GMaps API for that.

Depend on your level, i also can suggest you by postal code. Here in Canada, it work great since each county have his beggining of his postal code.